# How to efficiently update an HTML/ string dynamically in Python?

Tags: python, html, string

The objective is to update an HTML/ string dynamically given a list of `list_header'.

List to be inputted into the html list

```
list_header=['Coffee','Tea','Milk']
```

Predefined html template

```
html = """
   <tr>
       <th>List of header name:</th>
   </tr>
<ol>

</ol>
"""
```

Expected result

```
html = """
   <tr>
       <th>List of header name:</th>
   </tr>
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
"""
```

I tried to use the find and append approach as below, but it will omit the upper part

```
line = '<li> </li>'
index = line.find('</ol>')
output_line = line[:index] + list_header[0] + line[index:]
```

Thanks for any help in linking to good reference material.

Comment: Since you first assign to `line` with `line = '<li> </li>'`, you'll never find `'</ol>'` in there. In what context are you trying to do this? For most Python CMSes or simple web servers, there are templating engines and libraries that solve this problem for you.

Comment: Hi @Grismar, I would like to use the mne report module. One of the submodule require user to manually define the html template::https://jasmainak.github.io/mne-workshop-brown/preprocessing/mne-report#custom-html. Appreciate if you can share the libraries that you have in mind.

Comment: There are many, a broad selection is here https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating#Templating_Engines - have a look around. Another easy way of going about it is using the approach suggested in the page you linked yourself, putting references in the string and then replacing them using `str.format()` or a similar mechanism (for example regex from the `re` standard library).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes, one of the approach is predefined manually each of the list. But, this approach is not efficient if we have list that have different length at different use case.

Comment: Yeah, so you do something like `f'<ol><li>{'</li><li>'.join(list_elems)}</ol>'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `jinja` for this kind of project. `Jinja` is design just to help you achieve this:

```py
# python -m pip install —user Jinja2

from jinja2 import Template


list_headers = ['Coffee','Tea','Milk']

HTML = '''
 <tr>
       <th>List of header name:</th>
 </tr>
<ol>
{% for list_header in list_headers %}
  <li> {{ list_header }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
'''

template = Template(HTML)
res = template.render(list_headers=list_headers)

print(res)
```

Read more here [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/intro/) to get familiar with `jinja` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the content in a root element (`<html>` in the example), you can use [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
list_header=['Coffee','Tea','Milk']

html = """<html>
<tr>
    <th>List of header name:</th>
</tr>
<ol>

</ol></html>
"""
root = ET.fromstring(html)

for inner_text in list_header:
    list_elt = ET.Element('li')
    list_elt.text = inner_text
    root[1].append(list_elt)
print(ET.tostring(root).decode("utf-8"))
```

Output:

```
<html>
<tr>
    <th>List of header name:</th>
</tr>
<ol>

<li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li></ol></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to keep the HTML in a separate file.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <tr>
            <th>List of header name:</th>
        </tr>
        <ol>
            {items}
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then using python script generates each items (li) in ol tag.

```py
with open("/path/to/html", "r") as file:
    html_template = file.read()

rows = [f"<li>{item}</li>" for item in items]

html_template.format(list_items = ".".join(rows))
```